# Android AlertDialog Custom View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have searched on Stack Overflow about this topic. However, I couldn't find any similar questions.

I have an alert dialog with a custom layout. When I try to access any view in this custom layout by using `findViewById` method of alert dialog, I end up with null pointer exception.

The XML layout of custom dialog is this:

```
    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:text="@string/settings" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:text="Search Distance" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sb_distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="25"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_large" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code for accessing layout:

```java
AlertDialog settingsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).
                setTitle(R.string.settings)
                .setView(R.layout.layout_distance_settings)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Do sth here
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();

        SeekBar distanceSB = (SeekBar) settingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.sb_distance);
        distanceSB.setProgress(5);
        settingsDialog.show();
```

Creating layout by using layout inflater solves problem. However, I want to know what I am doing wrong in here.

Using layout inflater, everything is ok. Here is the code:

```java
AlertDialog settingsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
                    setTitle(R.string.settings)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            // Do sth here
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();

            View parentView = settingsDialog.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_distance_settings, null);

            SeekBar distanceSB = (SeekBar) parentView.findViewById(R.id.sb_distance);
            distanceSB.setProgress(5);
            settingsDialog.setView(parentView);
            settingsDialog.show();
```

So again my question is this: What is the correct way of using `setView` and how can I access child views of layout used as argument of `setView?`

Comment: Can you show the code that you used to inflate the view that did work?

Comment: setView method of alert dialog builder used to set custom layout.

Comment: I am asking about the code you wrote when you said "Creating layout by using layout inflater solves problem."  What did you write?  I want to compare it to the other code that you say is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You must inflate your layout first. To do that, we use the LayoutInflater class:

```
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_distance_settings,null);
```

and the pass it to the `setView()` method.

So your final code would be:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_distance_settings,null);
AlertDialog settingsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).
                setTitle(R.string.settings)
                .setView(dialogView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // Do sth here
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();

        SeekBar distanceSB = (SeekBar) settingsDialog.findViewById(R.id.sb_distance);
        distanceSB.setProgress(5);
        settingsDialog.show();
```

Comment: I know I can do it by inflating it. However, I used setView method of alert dialog builder. What is the correct way of setView usage? Or can I access view set by setView?

Comment: @ycagri to get a view, you can use dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sb_distance)

Comment: check out my updated question. I used AlertDialog.Builder setView method. In documentation, this method can take a layout resource id as parameter. I want to learn correct way of setView method of AlertDialog.Builder usage.